# Tailwind place-content-center not expanding vertically

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want this div centered in the bordered box on both axes:

[image]

[image]

```html
<div id='versions'>
  <div class="hidden only:flex place-content-center">
    <div class="text-center">
      <p class="mb-4 h3">Create your first Version</p>
      <a .... >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried just about all permutations I can think of to use `flex-col` and `flex-1`, `justify` and `center` classes, but nothing expands this content or stretches it vertically to center, or aligns vertically. What am I missing?